# Details on Windows Azure R2 Webrole: Files, Drives, and MSFT-scripts

Tags: web-server, windows-server-2008-r2, cloud-computing, azure

I'm using Remote Desktop to connect to an Azure Instance and I noticed the following for an extra-small instance of Windows 2008R2:

> C:\ Drive for the purpose of storing
>   log data.  13.6GB / 19.9GB used
>
> D:\
>   Drive for OS functions 17GB / 25.9
>   used
>
> E:\ Drive for my website, and is
>   the location for the [startup
>   tasks](http://blog.smarx.com/posts/asp-net-mvc-in-windows-azure) 100MB / .99GB used

There are many interesting files, batch files and settings there.  Does anyone have information on the configuration of the OS?

Does anyone have info what the batch files and scripts "do"?

I would love to see any rationale on why things were done this way so we can use the practices within our own IT department.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if Microsoft's model for pure automation surrounding the creation, management and destruction of millions of OS's is something of use to most IT departments, but I can give you my thoughts.  I don't have the actual official reasons from MS Online teams but here's my 2 cents based on the little I know:

Azure Windows is designed around rapid deployment, separation of "their OS" and "your data", and the ability for Microsoft to update/manage their OS without affecting your data.  Splitting these parts into separate drives is a clean way to do it.